# How to repair powerstate (intel_pstate) on Intel Haswell chips?

Tags: nvidia, power-management, battery, intel

I recently installed `tlp` on my Lenovo U430p laptop. After I runned it I noticed significant drop in my laptop's on bettery time. Now my laptop lasts on battery for 2 hours less than before.

After that I read on arch wiki page not to use it with other programs such as `powertop` which I used before, because it may overwrite the powerstates, which it did. My powerstates now looks this way:

```
+++ Processor
CPU Model      = Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  2080000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2080000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2600000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2600000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2600000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo          = 0
/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog                          = 0
```

As you can see all scaling governors are renamed to powersave and I think that means my Haswell i5 4200U processor rus all the time at maximum frequency.

So my question is: **How can I repair it?** I don't know how the states were named before.

I also noticed that my dedicated graphic card runs even on battery (which it didn't while I was using powertop only).

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This sysfs output looks fine, you are looking in the wrong place, it's the graphics card.

> As you can see all scaling governors are renamed to powersave and I think that means my Haswell i5 4200U processor rus all the time at maximum frequency.

That would be the `performance` govenor, `powersave` stands for conserve power. The `ondemand` govenor is not available with pstates.

Comment: I can safely say that this doesn't have anything to do with my dedicated graphic card, because I temporarily disabled it in BIOS without any battery-life impact.

_Edit: I manually set the frequency scaling on battery and it seems like it does the job just fine (I also disabled turbo while on battery)._